# remove short description validation in backend when adding / editing products

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I upgraded a store from version 1.3 to version 1.5 and noticed that the short description field when adding / editing a product is mandatory (which was not for version 1.3).

Could I know which file to edit to remove the validation on the short description field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to go to Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes, search for the Attribute Code `short_description`, click on the row, change `Value Required` to `No`.